# Typescript Object variable key mapping type

Tags: typescript

i have the problem that when logging `value.test` the error is thrown. This error occurs because TypeScript is not sure that the value of result is a key of the DATA object. I think that i should use generic type but not sure how to pass it via `.find` method

I want it cause i'm trying to define seperated inputs for each of object

`case type.name`

example code:

```
const DATA = {
  name: {
    label: "test",
    test: 123,
    baba: 12,
  },
  example: {
    abc: "abc",
    abs: "asd"
  },
  gender: "Male"
}

const testName = "name"
const result = Object.keys(DATA).find((d: string) => d === testName)
const value = DATA[result as keyof typeof DATA];

console.log(value.test);
```

typescript playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAIgQQCoJgXhgbwFAxmAQwFsBTALi1zxgBsCAjEmigIihOhYBoq93oKARgBMAZh7UY9BgSHCJMAL4KSAD2IAHGuUqSGwVvu68YDCIYgATFlWVUA5iTCWSAJ1YBZAtpuLs2UEhYfigAOWISdBgWQlIbQOgYVw4AVxpYDAB5egArEmAoADoAaxIATwgACkQUAEpCgDMAS2dKyssKaFcW+1r0AD4YS3Q0DBDw0lqA8ESAN28UyIwahABtZIg02AIIGFKykAaYKDKNEkP4ZAQAXQBufwSQbUKaEHtK+ZpFwpDa+-8gA

I've tried casting the type, and making it as mapped types but not sure how can i omit my error

Comment: `value` can be any of the properties of `DATA` and it can even be `undefined`.

Comment: Why this complicated logic with `Object.keys().find()`? What's wrong with `const value = DATA[testName];`?

Comment: it's only the example so everything is clear. In real code have to call API, and pass it down to another component ten loop an make input based on type from backend, so when I've got for example Date, there's only 1 object that contain F.E `StartDate` and `EndDate`

Comment: Don't attempt to write generic code for specific needs. It seems clever when you write it but you struggle to understand it later. Any piece of code is written once but read multiple times, by different developers (one of them is you, several months or years later). Let the code be easy to read, understand and modify.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your console.log like this:

```
if (typeof value === 'object' && 'test' in value) {
  console.log(value.test);
}
```

The first part of that condition ensures that it's not a string, and the second part ensures that 'test' is a property on the object.

Playground: https://tsplay.dev/mMzarW

Comment: I think that will help, thank you :)

Comment: @diegoturbak if this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check on the left.